# How do I install the Microsoft 6to4 Adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter, ipv6, teredo

I'm unable to see the 6to4/Teredo adapter anywhere in my Windows 7 installation. In my Device Manager, the only network adapters are my wireless Realtek card, and "TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS" which is for my OpenVPN.

`ipconfig /all` output:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : laptop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-16-D8-3D-34-3D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c19:6e2f:6e46:611c%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.112.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 20 August 2013 10:48:59
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 20 August 2013 11:04:04
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.112.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.200.112.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 387978968
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-96-51-21-20-16-D8-3D-34-3D

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.22.22
                                       192.168.22.23
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-6F-D7-85-4B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6FD7854B-74C3-4774-AB9B-8F07BBE4FE6D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

`route print` output:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...20 16 d8 3d 34 3d ......Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
 11...00 ff 6f d7 85 4b ......TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.200.112.1     10.200.112.3     40
     10.200.112.0  255.255.255.248         On-link      10.200.112.3    296
     10.200.112.3  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.200.112.3    296
     10.200.112.7  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.200.112.3    296
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.200.112.3    296
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.200.112.3    296
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    296 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    296 fe80::4c19:6e2f:6e46:611c/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    296 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

How can I install/enable the adapter?

Comment: You do understand you already have both a IPv6 and IPv4 address right?

Comment: in the device manager do you have "Show Hidden Devices" under view turned on? I had to ask, because I cant see

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think I do.

Comment: @Psycogeek Just did that and all that appeared was multiple WAN Miniports, one of which was IPv6. Nothing else.

Comment: @Aaron - Sure you do `20-16-D8-3D-34-3D
` that isn't a IPv4 address. Most service providers currently assign both a IPv4 and IPv6 address to their customers.

Comment: @Ramhound That's a MAC address, not an IPv6 address. There are no global IPv6 addresses shown here.

Answer (score 1):

6to4 only works when your system has a public IPv4 address. As you have private address `10.200.112.3` it is not possible to run 6to4 on this system.

6to4 is also very unreliable, so I advise you to avoid it. If you want IPv6 access you are much better off looking at reliable tunnel brokers like [Hurricane Electric](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/) and [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/).

Comment: HE's Tunnelbroker is what I'm trying to use. I think I'm supposed to use 6to4 to connect, but I couldn't find many guides out there, so I could be wrong.

Comment: No, you use a v6v4tunnel adapter for that. If you go to your tunnelbroker.net account look at the "Example Configurations" tab. You'll still need a public IPv4 address though (unless you can make your firewall forward protocol-41 packets to an internal PC)

Comment: 6to4 works fine for me (UPC Poland) Might depend on the ISP, though.

Comment: 6to4 depends on both the outbound relay (for traffic you send to the IPv6 internet) and the inbound relay (the traffic from the IPv6 internet to you). If 6to4 works for you then at least you (currently) have a good outbound relay. The inbound relay however depends on who you are talking to. If you talk to Google you will get traffic through the inbound relay that is closest to Google, etc. So 6to4 always remains unpredictable. Note that modern operating systems avoid 6to4 if they can and have a fast fallback to IPv4, so you might not even use it that much or notice its problems...